# div size adjustment with content generated from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I loaded a page into a div but I can't adjust the size of the div

here are code lines:

my css:

```
<style type="text/css">
#calendar {
width:350px;
float:left;
padding:10px;}
</style>
```

html:

```
.
.
<div id="calendar"></div>
.
.
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function divload(){
document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html"  
data="/ISMS/calendar/index.php"></object>'; }
</script>
```

should innerHTML with an object loaded be resized in another way?

thanks for anyhelp

Comment: size means height and width? In your css width is fixed and you can change dimensions as per your requirement. Provide more details about your issue.

Comment: yeah size and width, I tried changing the attributes in the css already

Comment: css applies at page load i.e. rendering. Use javascript to change them dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load the object into the `calendar` element, you can resize the div using JS.

```js
function divload(){
    var calDiv = document.getElementById("calendar"),
        height = "300px", // or whatever you want the new height to be
        width = "800px"; // or whatever you want the new width to be

    calDiv.innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="http://printartsportal.com/"></object>';

    calDiv.style.height = height;
    calDiv.style.width = width;

    calDiv.children[0].style.height = height;
    calDiv.children[0].style.width = width;
}
```

Comment: @lewd, yeah sorry.  I forgot to resize the `<object>` element inside of the div.  Thanks for pointing that out.